# no permission to modify static procedure (\= )/2 prolog error

Tags: compiler-errors, prolog

I was trying to write a rule to tell when is it possible for "A" to be the brother of "B" but I got one error and one warning the first error says :`no permission to modify static procedure (\= )/2` 
  and the warning says :`Singleton variables [A,B]`. I understand that the singleton variable means that variable is used only once, but I cant figure a way to fix my code however I don't understand the first error I'm a Prolog beginner so it might happen to be a silly mistake that I can't find.

```
 brother(A,B):-
    parent(X,A),
    parent(X,B),
    male(A).
 A \= B.
```

Comment: I just adjusted the indentation: Now you should see the error!

Comment: @false oh the full stop , my bad!

Comment: @false IMHO you should have provided the answer as an instead of adjusting the original question because others who might come here might not know how to view the original incorrect formatting.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Do you have evidence that people search SO by the very layout characters in code? I very much doubt that such an option exists. In general, I reformat question-code for layouts **only**. Should this question be of use to anyone, then rather by identifying the error message in the question. Also note that the originally missing indentation  after `:-` was certainly not intended.

Comment: @false The way I see people finding this is via `no permission to modify static procedure` Then when they look to see if it has an answer they will not see one.  Sure some people will read the question and comments and then see how this was answered, but other will not. Why not make it easy for those expecting to see a separate answer.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Why don't you write an answer?

Comment: @false Thanks I shall. I just didn't want you to think I was stealing the points. :)

Answer (score 6):

Note: @false gave the correct hint. This is just putting the answer in as an answer.

The original code the OP received an error from:

```erlang
brother(A,B):-
parent(X,A),
parent(X,B),
male(A).
A \= B.
```

and the error:

```erlang
ERROR: xyz.pl:8:
    No permission to modify static procedure `(\=)/2'
```

By changing the indentation as noted by @false

```erlang
brother(A,B):-
   parent(X,A),
   parent(X,B),
   male(A).  
A \= B.
```

It became obvious to the OP that there was a `full stop` with `male(A).` that should not be there.

Changing the code to

```erlang
brother(A,B):-
    parent(X,A),
    parent(X,B),
    male(A),
    A \= B.
```

removed the error.